# Submission makes page blank php

Tags: php, html, css, session

On my website I am making a fake login system, just to show people how my style sheet (that I have only worked on for about 2 days) works. Below I will link the page, the PHP code, and then a link to the CSS.
[Web-Page](http://matrix-hub.com/styles/mint/Mint.php)
  Get to the form by clicking the login/signup button, put any info in, it is just supposed to make the profile Guest button say Profile: (name you entered), get to html code with F12.
php below

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(isset($_POST['log'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($_POST['bio'] == "") {
        $bio = "No bio.";
        return $bio;
    } else {
        $bio = $_POST['bio'];
        return $bio;
    }
    $logged = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['bio'] = $bio;
    $_SESSION['logged'] = $logged;
} else {
    $username = "Guest";
    $password = "";
    $bio = "No bio - Guest";
    $logged = false;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['bio'] = $bio;
    $_SESSION['logged'] = $logged;
}
```

Now you can find the CSS at the following [Page](http://matrix-hub.com/styles/mint/Mint.css)
and since Goolge doesn't show php (for good reason, websites would be screwed if it did) here is the php for the profile button:

```
 <a class="option" href="profile.php">Profile: <?= $username; ?></a>
```

Comment: Remove two `return $bio;`

Comment: Ok, it works now, but can you explain why return $bio made it not work? @Mr.Blue

Comment: It stops execution when you call that.

Comment: If it's inside a function, then it stops execution of codes inside the function and returns a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `return $bio;` lines.

The `return` makes your script execution stop and return the value afterwards.

Read up on [return](http://php.net/manual/de/function.return.php)

Answer (score 0):

return $bio;

is exiting the function. Remove it.